# Is there a way to run Office.js code as soon as Excel has started up or when the manifest is loaded in?

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-web-addins

I want to register events at the earliest possible stage for Excel, is it possible to register those events upon starting Excel similar to how there is a [Startup event in VSTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/events-in-office-projects?view=vs-2019)? If that isn't possible, is there a way for me to run Office.js code to register events right after the manifest has finished loading into Excel?

Comment: You may try Office.onReady()? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in

Comment: Does this run every time Excel is opened up with add-in already installed or is this only when the user interacts with the add-in, for example, if the user clicks a button to run a UI-less function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that you may have a try. there is an auto-open feature can let task pane [open automatically when a document opens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document). With the auto-open feature, you can explicitly define or allow the user to define whether a specific task pane add-in persists in a specific document.

1. Specify the task pane to be opened automatically.

> ```
> <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
>     <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
>     <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
> </Action>
> ```

2. Tag the document to automatically open the task pane.

Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", true);
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();

3. Initialize with [Office.onReady()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in)

Comment: This could work! Although, is there a way I can do this without the use of a task pane or a UI of any sort?

Comment: Could you have a try with UI-less function, I am not sure if UI-Less function support auto-open feature